# Why the word "one" is ungrammatical?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, exam-questions

This is a TOEFL question.

> Astronomers use photography and sighting telescopes to study the
>   motion of all of the bright stars and many of the faint one.

I think the word "one" is grammatical, but the solution says that it's not grammatical :) I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs an "s" at the end.

You mention that there are multiple stars but then only reference one.

> The astronomer**s***(plural)* use photography and sighting telescope**s***(plural)*
>   to study the motion of all of the bright star**s** *(plural)*
>   and **many***(plural)* of the faint **one**.*(singular)*

Comment: Compare with: "The astronomers use photography and sighting telescopes
to study the motion of all of the bright stars
and the faint one." Here we don't have "many" faint stars, so we refer to "one" rather than "ones."